# Get Effective Access of a specific user on a OU in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a way in powershell to get the effective access of a specific user account, on a specific OU?  I am looking to write a script to see if a specific user has ActiveDirectoryRights on CreateChild and DeleteChild on a specific OU.

I have played with the command:

```
(Get-Acl 'AD:/OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=local').access 
| select identityreference, accesscontroltype, ActiveDirectoryRights
```

But this does not let me know if a specific user has the permission on that OU.